# Server Library [Glassfish 3.1.2.2] (unbound)

Tags: glassfish

Any ideea how to edit this error?from where to load the server Library?
I am using GlassFish-Tools-Bundle-For-Eclipse-1.2

Answer (score 0):

If this is some kind of bundle you should first download a normal Eclipse for Java EE from [www.eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

You should install the GlassFish Tools for your specific Eclipse version (probably Kepler) via the Eclipse Marketplace.

Click `Help` -> `Eclipse Marketplace` and search for **glassfish**.

After installing you can add your server instance via the `Servers` tab in Eclipse.